# How to identify CAShapeLayer within the animationDidStop

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have an array of `CAShapeLayer`. At some point I must iterate through that array and start an animation for each layer. Those animations change the `bounds.size.height` of the layers to different values (computed in some way). In the `animationDidStop` method I'd like to actually change the height of each layer to the `animation.toValue` value. I need to do this because I want the future animations to start from the new values and not from the initial values. This is the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<[layersArray count]; i++) {
    newLayerHeight = [self computeNewHeightForLayer:[layersArray objectAtIndex:i];

    CABasicAnimation *myAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size.height"];
    myAnim.delegate = self;
    myAnim.duration = 0.4;
    myAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    myAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    myAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[layersArray objectAtIndex:i]).bounds.size.height];
    myAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newLayerHeight];
    [[layersArray objectAtIndex:i] addAnimation:myAnim forKey:@"changeHeightAnim"];
}
```

In the `animationDidStop` method I'd like to do something like this (equivalent to this, actually; the if-else paradigm is not the best):

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if(flag){
        /*
            if(anim is linked to layer0)change the height of layer0;
            if(anim is linked to layer1)change the height of layer1;
            .
            .
            .
            if(anim is linked to layerN-1)change the height of layerN-1;

        */
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a specific value for each animation you set to each `CAShapeLayer` as you loop through your layers array, like so:

```
[myAnim setValue:@"layer_1" forKey:@"animation_id"];
[myAnim setValue:@"layer_2" forKey:@"animation_id"]; 
...
```

In your 'animationDidStop' method, check the value of the animation parameter for the value, like so:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if([[anim valueForKey:@"animation_id"] isEqual:@"layer_1"]) {
        // do something
    }
    else if([[anim valueForKey:@"animation_id"] isEqual:@"layer_2"]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've adopted a little bit different solution, but the core of the that solution is yours.